# Список из массива звуков ion.sound

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ув. знатоки понадобилась возможность наполнения списка select из массива.

Есть массив вот такого вида:

```
ion.sound({
        sounds: [
            {name: "join"},
            {name: "join1"},
            {name: "join2"},
            {name: "join3"},
            {name: "join4"},
            {name: "join5"} ],
    });
```

Как теперь создать выпадающий список select наполненный option из этого массива?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то
после подключения jQuery библиотеки делаем:

```
<script>
    var sounds = [
        {name: "join"},
        {name: "join1"},
        {name: "join2"},
        {name: "join3"},
        {name: "join4"},
        {name: "join5"}
    ];

    ion.sound({ sounds: sounds });

    var html = '<select>';
    for(var i in sounds) {
        html += '<option value="' + sounds[i].name + '">' + sounds[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    html += '</select>';

    $('#result').html(html);
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```